# Change preloadEnabled programmatically in .net core web app

Tags: asp.net, iis

Is there any way to set the preloadEnabled = "true" in IIS inside a .net core web application?

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If it doesn't work, could you please tell me what problem you get.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open IIS Manager and navigate to server level, click **Confiuration
   Editor**.
2. In section, choose **system.applicationHost** -> **sites**.
3. Click **...** in image and choose your .net core application.
   [image]
4. In **properties**, choose **True** and back to the Configuration Editor interface, click **Apply**.
   [image]

If you enable preload, it is necessary to set application pool always running so that it will be useful.
[image]